# Merging multiple feature classes into one feature class

Tags: merge

I have several feature classes in different geodatabases and I am trying to merge into one feature class, same geometry one attribute table in one geodatabase (attribute fields are the same).

It keeps coming out as a shapefile which I cannot have as it gets rid of my domains. How do I merge and have a resulting single feature class and/or is there something else I should use other than the merge tool?

Background: Several feature classes originally in their own geodatabase. I copied them to a single geodatabase. The feature classes are polyline culvert data originally collected with a Trimble GPS Unit.

I do not know how to script or use Python yet so I am trying to do this using the GUI.

Comment: Save the output merge into a geodatabase and the output will not be a shapefile. It seems your saving into a folder.

Comment: What software are you using? ArcGIS Desktop, ArcGIS Pro, QGIS, or other software, please specify.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you just using the 'merge' tool from the menu?

Comment: In this case I copy the first database as the output and then append the others - guaranteed not to break your subtypes and domains but you can get some mismatched values if the domains are different; you say they're the same so this method should work. Optionally you can delete every other feature class in the database if that makes the result easier to use... hope that little hack helps.

Comment: I'm using 10.5 desktop but I can use ArcGIS Pro. I am using the merge tool from the Menu (merge data management). I have tried saving into one geodatabase as the output and it still comes out as a shapefile.

Comment: Michael Stimson-I am not sure what you mean by append. I am also confused to why it would work with the first database and not a new one I created. There are several with one feature class each in them, so I thought it would make sense to make a new one.